# How to use multiple glViewport() and glOrtho()

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl, opengl-compat

I am trying to use pygame and pyopengl, in the main window i have 2 viewports
1 big map and 1 minimap (both presenting the same frame). i need both maps to rotate around a center who isnt 0,0,0 (lets say i need the center of rotation to be -130,0,60 which needs to be a constant point)

also i need 1 view to view a distance of `glTranslatef(0, 0, -1000)`
and the 2nd view to be `glTranslatef(1, 1, -200)` both distances are constant

i tried to use

```
gluLookAt()
glOrtho()
```

but it doesnt change the rotation.... around 0,0,0
or i might be using it wrong.

the code looks like this:

```
pygame.init()
display = (1700, 1000)
pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)
gluPerspective(50, (display[0] / display[1]), 0.1, 5000)
glTranslatef(0, 0, -1000) # this is the view distance i want from map 1
while True:

   ##### i use this function to zoom in and out with mouse Wheel
   ##### also the zoom in/out zooms to 0,0,0 and i need (-130,0,60)
   if move_camera_distance:
        if zoom_in:
            glScalef(0.8,0.8,0.8)
        elif zoom_out:
            glScalef(1.2, 1.2, 1.2)
        move_camera_distance = False
        zoom_in = False
        zoom_out = False        


    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    ###### Map 1 
    ###### Need to rotate around (-130,0,60)
    ###### distance from camera need to be (0,0,-1000)
    glViewport(1, 1, display[0], display[1])  # splits the screen
    glCallList(obj.gl_list)
    DrawBuffer(bufferObj, noPoints, noCirclePoints, noCrossPoints) 


    ###### Map 2
    ###### Need to rotate around (-130,0,60)
    ###### distance from camera need to be (0,0,-300)
    glViewport(1300, 650, 400, 400)  # splits the screen
    glCallList(obj.gl_list)
    DrawBuffer(bufferObj, noPoints, noCirclePoints, noCrossPoints)

    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.wait(10)
```

The output i get is 2 maps, both rotate around 0,0,0 both are from a distance of (0,0,-1000) and both change together if i change anything in the While loop. 
thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the current matrix can be stored to the matrix stack by [`glPushMatrix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml) and restored from the matrix stack by `glPopMatrix`. There are different matrix modes and matrix stacks (e.g. `GL_MODELVIEW`, `GL_PROJECTION`). See ([`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml)).

Set the projection matrix at initialization and set different modelview matrices for the different views:

```py
glMatrxMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glLoadIdentity()
gluPerspective(50, (display[0] / display[1]), 0.1, 5000)

glMatrxMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadIdentity()
# [...]

while True:

    ###### Map 1 
    glViewport(1, 1, display[0], display[1])  # splits the screen

    glPushMatrix()
    glTranslatef(0, 0, -1000) # this is the view distance i want from map 1
    # [...]
    glPopMatrix()


    ###### Map 2
    glViewport(1300, 650, 400, 400) # splits the screen

    glPushMatrix()
    glTranslatef(0, 0, -300) # this is the view distance i want from map 1
    # [...]
    glPopMatrix()
```

---

To rotate the model around a point, you've to:

- Translate the model in that way that way, that the pivot is in the origin of the world. This is a translation by the inverse pivot vector.
- Rotate the model.
- Translate the rectangle in that way that the pivot is back at its original position.

In the program, this operations have t o be applied in revers order, because operations like [`glTranslate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTranslate.xml) and [`glRotate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRotate.xml) define a matrix and multiply the matrix to the current matrix:

```cpp
glTranslatef(-130, 0, 60);
glRotate( ... )
glTranslatef(130, 0, -60);
```

Do this immediately before you draw the object.

Comment: worked like a charm! thanks! 
1 more question, if i want to rotate only one map how can i do it?
right now it rotates them both

Comment: @RonLevin You've to do the rotation in between `glPushMatrix()` and `glPopMatrix()`.